# Can't access @Value in Spring project accross different packages and Environment doesn't contain the values either

Tags: java, spring

I cannot access `@Value("${app.version}")` or event `environment.getProperty("app.version")` or any property in my controllers or services.

My project structure looks like this

```
src/main/java

    -configuration/
       AppConfig.java
       EnvConfig.java
       JpaConfig.java
       UiConfig.java
       ServicesConfig.java
       UiAppInitializer.java

    -repositories/
       ....
    -models/
       ....
    -services/
       ....
    -controllers/
       ....
```

My UiAppInitializer is pretty straight forward,
`getRootConfigClassess()` returns `AppConfig.class` and `getServletConfigClasses()` returns `UiConfig.class`

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@Import({
EnvConfig.class,
UiConfig.class,
ServicesConfig.class
})
public class AppConfig{}
```

EnvConfig

```
@Configuration
public class EnvConfig implements InitializingBean {

    @Value("${app.version}")
    private String appVersion
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        pc.setLocations(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
        return pc;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterpropertiesSet() throws Exception {
      log.debug("App Version is " + appVersion);
    }
}
```

A simple controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/version")
public class VersionContoller {

    @Value("${app.version}")
    private String version;

    @GetMapping()
    public String getVersion() {
           return version;
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "my.packages.path.ui"
})
public class UiConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
   ....
}
```

The controller just returns "${app.version}" but the `afterpropertiesSet` correctly logs the version.

What am I doing wrong here? I have other controllers that connect to the repository successfully which was setup in JpaConfig that usues `@Value` for all the properties also

Note not using Spring Boot

Answer (score 0):

It seems the controller is getting initialised as a bean before the `properties()` bean has had `setLocations()` called. 
You could remove classpath scanning (I assume you have it on to find the controller bean?) and in your EnvConfig declare a new method that is a bean declaration for the Controller that passes in the version String. Obviously requiring a change to the controller constructor too

```
@Configuration
public class EnvConfig implements InitializingBean {

    @Value("${app.version}")
    private String appVersion
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        pc.setLocations(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
        return pc;
    }

    @Bean
    public VersionContoller controller() {
        return new VersionController(appVersion);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterpropertiesSet() throws Exception {
      log.debug("App Version is " + appVersion);
    }
}
```

Comment: My UiConfig class implements `WebMvcConfigurer` and enablesWebMVC and does the scanning for the controllers. 

So would I have to create every controller there then? That doesn't seem right. But I agree it does seem like the controllers are getting setup to fast/early. I tried using Order but that didn't seem to change. I'll update my question with the ui config

Comment: Yeah that doesn't seem right. I'm not sure tbh. Spring Boot would take care of this problem without the need for defining the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean so I assume there is a reason you can't/don't want to use it.

Comment: Haha there is definitely a reason, I would much rather be using boot than fiddling with all of this. But maybe if I load the properties in AppConfig, and move all the rest of the imports into Env instead? And only import Env in AppConfig... i dont know